# Orchard MenuProvider GetMenu not getting triggerred by Dependency Injection

Tags: orchardcms

I am using Orchard framework in our project and leveraging the IMenuProvider to build the menu. The code works fine and the method GetMenu gets invoked in all the environments (US servers) however in one of our client's server (German) the GetMenu method doesn't get invoked and hence the menu doesn't come up. Any help from the Orchard framework experts is appreciated.

Code is as below -

```
public class MenuProvider : IMenuProvider
{
public MenuProvider(IOrchardServices services, ICacheManager cachemanager, IClock clock, ISignals signals, IWebSiteFolder websiteFolder)
{
}

public void GetMenu(Orchard.ContentManagement.IContent menu, NavigationBuilder builder)
{
  // Menu building logic here
}
}
```

Comment: Is the feature enabled?

Comment: What feature did you mean ? I believe all basic modules are enabled, because the same deployed code works fine on other servers as is.